# What is exactly the asymptotic form of Bessel function?

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

My differential equations book says that
$$J_0(x)\simeq\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
for "large $x$."
It calls it an "asymptotic approximation."
My natural questions are: It is an approximation in what sense? Does their difference go to zero as $x\to\infty$ ? Or does their ratio go to 1 as $x\to\infty$ ? How large should $x$ be in order to reduce the error within a specific level? Or is it even possible?

Comment: See https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17 and https://doi.org/10.1007/s10440-017-0099-0

Comment: The ratio cannot go to one since the roots of the two sides do not agree.